# Running a synchronous method asynchronously

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run a synchronous method asynchronously so I can update the UI with its progress. I have to run this same synchronous method with several different pieces of data, but there can only be one instance of this method at a time.

This is what I've tried, and this isn't exactly what my program looks like but I've simplified it to minimize confusion.

```
class Program
{
    static int[] data = new int[10]
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Method(0);
    }

    static void Method(int parameter)
    {
        if (parameter < data.Length)
        {
            Worker worker = new Worker();
            worker.OnProgressChange += delegate
            {
                // Update UI
            };
            worker.OnWorkComplete += delegate
            {
                Method(parameter++);
            };
            worker.DoWork();
        }
    }
}

class Worker
{
    public event EventHandler OnProgressChange;
    public event EventHandler OnWorkComplete;

    public Worker() { }

    public void DoWork() { }
}
```

I'm not sure how to attack this. Please let me know if I'm not explaining the problem well enough.

Comment: I didn't understand your question, but I think your answer illustrates what you are trying to achieve.  You want to do some heavy processing (converting a collection of files) that will take some time to finish.  You want your application's thread of execution to be held up until the file processing is complete, but you want Windows to be responsive.  Is that correct?

Comment: @mbeckish I want the UI thread to be active and non-frozen. With that in mind, I'm trying to convert a list of files, only one at a time though. That's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution! The answer isn't going to apply to the abstracted scenario I've presented above, but the idea is the same.

```
    private bool flag = false;

    private void CheckCompletion()
    {
        // Do stuff

        ConvertFiles();
        while (!flag)
            Application.DoEvents();

        // Do more stuff
    }

    private void ConvertFiles()
    {
        UpdateStatus("Converting...", true);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (Engine engine = new Engine())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
                {
                    MediaFile inputFile = new MediaFile(entries[i].FilePath);
                    MediaFile outputFile = new MediaFile(entries[i].FilePath.Replace(".aac", ".mp3"));
                    engine.ConvertProgressEvent += (obj, args) =>
                    {
                        int value = (int)Math.Round(args.ProcessedDuration.TotalSeconds /
                            args.TotalDuration.TotalSeconds);
                        Invoke(new Action(delegate { entries[i].ProgressBarEx.Value = value; }));
                    };
                    engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
                }
            }
            flag = true;
        });
    }
```

If you need to run a synchronous method asynchronously, use the task parallel library. If you need to run several instances of that asynchronously running synchronous task, but only one at a time, put a `for loop` inside that task and have a `bool` variable tell the application when all tasks are complete. It's the `while(!flag) Application.DoEvents();` that is the pure magic.

I'm sorry if any of what I've said was too confusing.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good way to do this.  You have a tight `while` loop that will keep getting its time slice over and over just to yield to the system.  .NET provides better built-in ways to tackle this.

Comment: @mbeckish I can't say that it is a good way to do this. But it was the only way that I could come up with. Please if you have a better idea, let me know! The reason I asked this question on SO was not just to get a way to do it but to make sure that the method I implemented was a good method to have.

Answer (score 0):

.NET already did it for you: [BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Basically all you need to do, is change your Method parameters to confine with BackgroundWorker `(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)` and call `RunWorkAsync`

Comment: Code sample included (the Fibonacci one is better :)

Comment: Thanks, but I know how I can run a synchronous method asynchronously. What I need to do is synchronously run a synchronous method asynchronously multiple times.

Comment: Hahahaha, if you understand what I mean.